# Hide buttons when making a screenshot UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions

Tags: ios, objective-c

is there a way to hide specific buttons (IBAction) when making a screenshot with UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions ?

I'm using the code below:

```
 // Define the dimensions of the screenshot you want to take (the entire screen in this case)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *sourceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //now we will position the image, X/Y away from top left corner to get the portion we want
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
    [sourceImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, -20)];
    UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage,nil, nil, nil);
```

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: What do you mean **specific buttons, when making a screenshot**, Can't just hide the button and revoke it at the end of it.

Answer (score 2):

Add outlet to each button on you view and setHidden = YES,

Else you can do this

```
for(UIView *v in self.view.subviews){
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        [v setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, can you be please a little more specific with your code because I'm still try to figure out Objective-C. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add this code before take screenshot code which you pasted in your question. This will work.

Comment: Buttons are still showing up in the screenshot when using your method above. I added your code right under: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);`

Comment: do not write under this line instead write above this line. Its because we have to hide before taking picture.

Comment: Nope, that didn't do the trick. Button still shows up in the screenshot. What about your first methode setHidden = YES, is this per button?

Comment: not possible. It should work.
Yes first method is about per button. Add outlet to each button and hide them before taking screenshot.

Comment: can you please share the code, something is wrong. This is not possible both solutions are not working. You are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)doButton {

    UIActionSheet *doSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take a Picture", @"Select from Album", nil];

    [doSheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = NO;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }
    if(buttonIndex == 1) {

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = NO;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }
}


#pragma mark - Image Picker Controller delegate methods

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    for(UIView *v in self.view.subviews){
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            [v setHidden:YES];
    }

    // Define the dimensions of the screenshot you want to take (the entire screen in this case)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *sourceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //now we will position the image, X/Y away from top left corner to get the portion we want
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
    [sourceImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, -20)];
    UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage,nil, nil, nil);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share Now"
                                                    message:@"Share or save now bla bla bla"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"No Thanks!"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Yes Share",nil];
    [alert performSelector:@selector(show) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.2];

}


// callback for UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {

    if (error) {
        // Handle if the image could not be saved to the photo album
    }
    else {
        // The save was successful and all is well
    }
}
```

Comment: I also added the following in .h file: `IBOutlet UIButton *doButton;`